# How do these different gcc linking options change the final executable?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, ncurses

I am trying to understand how libraries and linking in gcc work. I'm trying to compile [an example](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/helloworld.html) `ncurses` "Hello World" program from a file test.c:

```cpp
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();                      /* Start curses mode              */
    printw("Hello World !!!");      /* Print Hello World              */
    refresh();                      /* Print it on to the real screen */
    getch();                        /* Wait for user input */
    endwin();                       /* End curses mode                */

    return 0;
}
```

I first compiled it (without a makefile) using this command:

```
gcc test.c -o test.exe -lncurses
```

This produced a 9kb file. After not understanding what the `-lncurses` switch did, I read a bit about linking, then about static and dynamic, and decided I wanted to try compiling statically à la [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3515002/2246637):

```
gcc -static test.c -o test.exe -lncurses
```

However, for some reason, that didn't work, and produced tons of `ld` 'undefined reference to x' errors. Example:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.a(lib_echo.o): In function `echo':
(.text+0x3): undefined reference to `SP'
```

From somewhere else, I added in an `-L/usr/lib` option:

```
gcc -static test.c -o test.exe -L/usr/lib -lncurses
```

This created a larger file, 1103kb.
I can understand why that should be bigger.
What I don't understand is why removing just the `-static` option:

```
gcc test.c -o test.exe -L/usr/lib -lncurses
```

... produces a file 184kb in size, even though it isn't statically linked to the `ncurses` library.

What is the -L/usr/lib option doing here? According to the [online docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html), it adds the directory "*to the list of directories to be searched for -l*". The /usr/lib directory has a `libncurses.a` file (amongst others) while the /usr/include contains a an `ncurses.h` symlinked to `curses.h` and an `ncurses_dll.h`. Is perhaps the `libncurses.a` file *not* a dynamic library? What is `ncurses.h` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely the way you want to build it:

```
gcc test.c -o test -lncurses
```

This says: "compile `test.c`, name the output file `test` and dynamically link the library (or shared object) called `libncurses.so` (the `lib` prefix is automatically added).

Note that the `.exe` suffix is not used on Linux, just Windows (your question is tagged with `linux` so I assume that is the platform you are using here).

If you statically link like this:

```
gcc -static test.c -o test.exe -lncurses
```

then the linker will look for a static version of the library (ie. `libncurses.a`). You get a whole bunch of linker errors, as it cannot resolve the references to the library functions, which suggests you don't have a static version of the library. Unless you have a really good reason to link statically, the norm is to use dynamic linking.

The next command just specifies some additional (but redundant) library paths:

```
gcc -static test.c -o test.exe -L/usr/lib -lncurses
```

This is simply telling the linker to search in `/usr/lib` when looking for libraries. However, `/usr/lib` is already in the default path, so this shouldn't ordinarily make a difference. If you run `gcc -dumpspecs` it will print all the paths and definitions that have been 'baked in' to the tool, and thus what the default search paths are for include files, libraries and so on.

> The /usr/lib directory has a libncurses.a file (amongst others) while the /usr/include contains a an ncurses.h symlinked to curses.h and an ncurses_dll.h. Is perhaps the libncurses.a file not a dynamic library? What is ncurses.h then?

The symlinks are present for backwards compatibility. The `ncurses` library (for "new curses") supersedes the original `curses`, but provides `curses.h` so old code can still build and run.  The `ncurses_dll.h` header provides some definitions only used for compiling on cygwin or MSVC under Windows, so you can ignore it. The `ncurses.h` is the real primary header for the library, and should be used for new code.

Comment: Ah, I was getting confused between libraries and headers. However, I can't find a `libncurses.so` file on my system, and the fact remains that using `-L/usr/lib` does change the file size (implying that there is static linking going on) and I can't compile statically unless I use that option. Do you any idea why I can dynamically linking without a .so file? And though `/usr/lib` is in my gcc path, things change when I include it...?

Comment: The `-L/usr/lib` doesn't make any difference. You must be running the 64-bit flavour of Linux, so the binaries will be in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` instead. I tried to replicate your commands to find a file size difference, and got 8697 bytes with both commands. Can you try again to be sure? Also, you can use the `ldd` command on your binary to dump which shared libraries it is using.

Comment: Huh - `libncurses.so` does exist, in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. `ldd` tells me that the first file is linked to 64-bit libraries, as you said. `ldd` shows me less information on the `-L/usr/lib` command, none to do with `ncurses`.  I can only statically link with the `-L/usr/lib` option. The `/usr/lib/libncurses*` files are all new, because I compiled and installed them yesterday (misunderstood where the libraries were actually stored). That might be part of my problem. In any case, this has solved a few of my problems, because I understand a lot better what is going on. Thank you!

Comment: You should have mentioned you compiled your own library. In that case, you shouldn't have installed it into `/usr/lib`, but rather into `/usr/local/lib` (or maybe `/opt/lib`). The system manages everything except `local` under `/usr`, and things can get confused if you mix user-built stuff with system-managed stuff.  As a general rule, most distros will package the runtime libraries with a name like `libncurses5` and the developer components (headers, libraries, man pages etc, only required for compilation) as `libncurses5-dev`. Always use system packages when possible.