# Create static library including ncurses

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, ncurses, unix-ar

I want to create a static library implementing a TUI interface using ncurses. I'm new to this topic and applying these answers didn't work
out for me.

- [rpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562403/i-dont-understand-wl-rpath-wl)
- [combine multiple libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128/how-to-combine-several-c-c-libraries-into-one)

I want to link varViewer.c in a library. I use this code to compile a example file.

Compiling src/example.c and src/viewer/varViewer.c:

```
    gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wnonnull  -Isrc/viewer/
     -c src/example.c -o obs/example.o -lncurses
     -fsanitize=undefined -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Winline -O2
    gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wnonnull  -Isrc/viewer/ 
     -c src/viewer/varViewer.c -o obs/viewer/varViewer.o -lncurses
     -fsanitize=undefined -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Winline -O2
```

Linking obs/example.o to bin/example:

```
    gcc -o bin/example -Isrc/viewer/
     obs/example.o obs/viewer/varViewer.o -lncurses
     -fsanitize=undefined -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Winline -O2
```

bin/example works as expected. I tried to compile a suitable object file:

Compiling src/viewer/varViewer.c:

```
    gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wnonnull  -Isrc/viewer/
    -c src/viewer/varViewer.c -o lib/objects/varViewer.o
    -lncurses -fPIC -O2
```

and put it into library:

```
    ar -cvr lib/libvarViewer.a lib/objects/varViewer.o
```

when I try to use it in other projects, a include it using

> -L ..../src/viewer/lib -lvarViewer

flags but all references to functions I used from ncurses library and 
string.h are undefined:

> nm /lib/libvarViewer.a

```
                .... 
             U __snprintf_chk
             U __stack_chk_fail
             U start_color
             U stdscr
             U strchr
             U strlen
             U strncmp
             U strncpy
             U strnlen
             U waddnstr
             U wborder
             U wclear
             U wcolor_set
             U wgetnstr
             U winsdelln
             U winsnstr
             U wmove
             U wrefresh
```

What is the correct way to call ar? I already tried to produce a "thin" library using -T option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wnonnull  -Isrc/viewer/
-c src/viewer/varViewer.c -o lib/objects/varViewer.o
-lncurses -fPIC -O2
```

will simply compile the varViewer.c file and thus, will ignore the libraries because it won't link to a final executable.

Consequently, the object file varViewer.o will have undefined references (`U` reported in `nm` as you have shown) to the symbols not defined within varViewer.c. These not only include the libncurses library but also the regular libc library (which provides symbols such as `strlen`, `strncpy`, ...). However, remember that `libc` will be automatically added into your link stage by the compiler unless you explicitly state otherwise.

You *could* use the command `ar x` to extract the object files (.o) from other static libraries and then use `ar` again to generate a new library. While this is possible I don't think that including all the libraries into yours is a good idea. I think that it is better to link against all the libraries needed because that ensures that the application is linked against the latest version available -- while if you embed one library into yours, then will stick to that version until you upgrade it.

Comment: Thank you:-) I tried to follow your advice and linked against ncurses lib. Unfortunately when I try to link against `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.a` using `gcc -I../viewer/lib garbage.c -L../viewer/lib/ -lvarViewer -l:libncurses.a`  I get a lot of undefined references while
`gcc -I../viewer/lib garbage.c -L../viewer/lib/ -lvarViewer -lncurses` works.
Am I missing something? According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514852/statically-link-ncurses-to-program?rq=1) this should work.

Comment: Undefined references to which symbols?

Comment: I try to summarizes it:

In functions I wrote macros like `COLS, LINES, stdscr` are undefined.
In functions from libncurses some terminal related symbols (tparm, SP, cur_term, ...) are missing:

example:
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.a(lib_box.o): In function `wborder':
    (.text+0x1f): undefined reference 'acs_map'

Comment: Those are in `libtinfo.a`